# Left join that defaults to zero if no results found?

Tags: mysql

I have a database of posts for my website. I am trying to return inside the query if the user has voted and if they have return the type of vote.

Here is my query

```
    SELECT p.*, 
        (SELECT Count(id) 
        FROM   comments AS c 
        WHERE  c.post = p.id) AS commentCount,
        v.type AS vote_type
   FROM   posts AS p 
   LEFT JOIN votes AS v
   ON v.post_id = p.id
   WHERE v.user_id = 1
   ORDER  BY timestamp DESC
```

Although this does return the field vote_type with the correct data, It also limits the results to those that have a vote for that user. So rather than showing all posts it will only show posts that the user has voted on? Is there a way to have the field default to 0 if there was no result found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

Eventhough you have used `LEFT JOIN` the `WHERE` clause which says `v.user_id = 1`. So all others (where `user_id` is `null`) are not being fetched.

**Solution:**

Add one condition to your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT p.*, 
        (SELECT Count(id) 
        FROM   comments AS c 
        WHERE  c.post = p.id) AS commentCount,
        v.type AS vote_type
   FROM   posts AS p 
   LEFT JOIN votes AS v 
   ON v.post_id = p.id
   WHERE (v.user_id = 1 OR v.user_id IS NULL)
   ORDER  BY timestamp DESC
```

**OR**

You can also specify it in the `JOIN` itself,

```
SELECT p.*, 
        (SELECT Count(id) 
        FROM   comments AS c 
        WHERE  c.post = p.id) AS commentCount,
        v.type AS vote_type
   FROM   posts AS p 
   LEFT JOIN votes AS v 
   ON v.post_id = p.id AND v.user_id = 1
   ORDER  BY timestamp DESC
```

Comment: The first solution works great. What are the benefits between the solutions? Should I choose one of the other?

Comment: @user1527354: Both are same. Both will work great. Yet, first one is a little more easy to understand.